# A better alternative to Microsoft Access?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, workflow, command-prompt

I've been using Microsoft Access for a few years but I'm starting to lament the lack of command line in the development interface. I use a couple of command line prompt programs for design and web development, so when I have to do something in Access, it seems so slow to have to scroll through Form Properties and Access Objects to find what I want to edit.

I'm wondering what other options are out there for making personal use databases (just desktop, don't need web). I'm just interested in solutions that I could implement as an individual, not on a corporate scale.

Or maybe there's a plugin or workflow for Access that I don't know about?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...  There's an obvious way to set form/object properties and control Access without scrolling through the UI.  Perhaps it's time to become more familiar with VBA.  This post is off-topic (see [help/on-topic]) but I'm curious what this "plugin or workflow" you're seeking would *do*? Also I'm not aware of any distinction in database platforms (including Access) that is considered to be for "personal use".

Comment: I'm also curious of examples of what you would want to run on a command line, if there were one available for Access.  I suppose Access does have a command line available, being a place you can enter commands to run immediately: the [immediate window](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/vbadebug2010/debug07.php).

Comment: SQLite... an in-process, self-contained, SQL compliant, desktop database with libraries available for many programming languages and OSes.  But this is essentially "all code".  There are some visual 3rd-party utilities for managing the database, but it's the other extreme from Access where you'll have to code everything and it is only a database, no forms, no reports, no visual query designers and datasheets.  For all that you'd need to use the host languages libraries and resources.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you going at here. I mean, when is the command line prompt used in say Visual Studio for development purposes, or to change anything in an application?

You can certainly use the command prompt much like say the “famous” “dot” prompt in FoxPro. So you can hit ctrl-g, and then type in say a sql command, or a command to call/run some of your code.  I type in commands all day long into the command prompt. And then of course you can always flip the sql editor into raw SQL view.

Take a quick view of this video where “jump” to the command prompt to update some data.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wdjYIby_b0

In fact here is the above video (with timestamp) that will show you how I use the command prompt:

https://youtu.be/3wdjYIby_b0?t=340

(so click on 2nd link to see me using the command line in Access during "normal" development.

I can safe say compared to say FoxPro, visual studio and most development “IDEs” that the use of the command line interface in Access is used “MORE” than those other environments.

You can also create windows scripting (batch processing) files to automate Access. How this is done in explained this in article of mine:

Batch processing in ms-access (how to run ms-access as a batch job).
http://www.kallal.ca/BatchJobs/Index.html

So, really no real shortcoming in Access as compared to “most” mainstream development tools out there. Typing in sql, code to call a routine etc. is “often” done in Access, and in fact more so then say Visual studio since Access does not require a full re-build and re-compile of the application like many systems do.